# Stack Overflow error when compiling a program

Tags: java

I am trying to create and relate four classes such as shape, circle, rectangle and square using inheritance as shown below. [image]

However, when I compile the program, the error message is displayed as shown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Square.setSide(Square.java:20)
```

I am not sure why is this so. Attached below are my codings

Square.java

```
public class Square extends Rectangle {
    public Square() {
        super();
    }

public Square(double side) {
    super(side, side);
}

public Square(double side, String color, boolean filled) {
    super(side, side, color, filled);  
}

public double getSide() {
    return getSide();
}

public void setSide(double side) {
    this.setSide(side);
}

public void setWidth(double side) {
    this.setWidth(getWidth());
}

public void setLength(double side) {
    this.setLength(getLength());
}

public String toString() {
    return "Square[Rectangle" + "[" + "Shape" + "[" + "color=" + getColor() + "," + "filled=" + isFilled() + "]," + "width=" + getWidth() + "," + "length=" + getLength() + "]";
}
}
```

Rectangle.java

```
public class Rectangle extends Shape {

private double length;
private double width;

public Rectangle() {
    this.length = 1.0;
    this.width = 1.0;
}

public Rectangle(double length, double width)
{
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
}

public Rectangle(double width, double length, String color, boolean filled) {
    super(color, filled);
    this.width = width;
    this.length = length;
}

public double getWidth()
{
    return this.width;
}

public void setWidth(double width)
{
    this.width = width;
}

public double getLength()
{
    return this.length;
}

public void setLength(double length)
{
    this.length = length;
}

public double getArea() {
    return length * width;
}

public double getPerimeter() {
    return 2*length + 2*width;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Rectangle[Shape" + "[color=" + getColor() + "," + "filled=" + isFilled() + "]," + "width=" + width + "," + "length=" + length + "]";
}




}
```

Circle.java

```
public class Circle extends Shape {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    private double radius;


    public Circle() {
        this.radius = 1.0;

    }

    public Circle(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public Circle(double radius, String color, boolean filled) {
        super(color,filled);
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return this.radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return radius * radius * Math.PI;
    }

    public double getPerimeter() {
        return 2 * Math.PI * radius;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Circle[Shape" + "[color=" + getColor() + "," + "filled=" + isFilled() + "]," + "radius=" + radius + "]";
    }



}
```

Shape.java

```
public class Shape {
private String color;
private boolean filled;

public Shape() {
    this.color = "red";
    this.filled = true;
}

public Shape(String color, boolean filled) {
    this.color = color;
    this.filled = filled;
}

public String getColor() {
    return this.color;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public boolean isFilled() {
    return this.filled;
}

public void setFilled(boolean filled) {
    this.filled = filled;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Shape[color=" + color + "," + "filled=" + filled + "]";
}

}
```

It would be better if someone can help me on that. Many thanks!

P.S The output was supposed to be like this

```
//Need copy the below codings for output


public class TestMain {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      /* Test Shape class */
      // Test constructors and toString()
      Shape s1 = new Shape();
      System.out.println(s1);  // toString()
      Shape s2 = new Shape("green", false);
      System.out.println(s2);  // toString()
      // Test Setters and Getters
      s1.setColor("blue");
      s1.setFilled(true);
      System.out.println(s1);  // toString()
      System.out.println("Color is: " + s1.getColor());
      System.out.println("Filled is: " + s1.isFilled());

  /* Test Circle class */
  // Test constructors and toString()
  Circle c1 = new Circle();
  System.out.println(c1);
  Circle c2 = new Circle(1.1);
  System.out.println(c2);
  Circle c3 = new Circle(2.2, "green", false);
  System.out.println(c3);
  // Test Setters and Getters
  c1.setColor("orange");  // superclass
  c1.setFilled(true);     // superclass
  c1.setRadius(8.8);
  System.out.println(c1);
  System.out.println("Color is: " + c1.getColor());  // superclass
  System.out.println("Filled is: " + c1.isFilled()); // superclass
  System.out.println("Radius is: " + c1.getRadius());
  System.out.printf("Area is: %.2f%n", c1.getArea());
  System.out.printf("Perimeter is: %.2f%n", c1.getPerimeter());

  /* Test Rectangle class */
  // Test constructors and toString()
  Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle();
  System.out.println(r1);
  Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(1.1, 2.2);
  System.out.println(r2);
  Rectangle r3 = new Rectangle(3.3, 4.4, "green", false);
  System.out.println(r3);
  // Test setters and getters
  r1.setWidth(5.5);
  r1.setLength(6.6);
  r1.setColor("orange");  // superclass
  r1.setFilled(true);     // superclass
  System.out.println(r1);
  System.out.println("Color is: " + r1.getColor());  // superclass
  System.out.println("Filled is: " + r1.isFilled()); // superclass
  System.out.println("Length is: " + r1.getLength());
  System.out.println("Width is: " + r1.getWidth());
  System.out.printf("Area is: %.2f%n", r1.getArea());
  System.out.printf("Perimeter is: %.2f%n", r1.getPerimeter());

  /* Test Square class */
  // Test constructor and toString()
  Square sq1 = new Square();
  System.out.println(sq1);
  Square sq2 = new Square(1.1);
  System.out.println(sq2);
  Square sq3 = new Square(2.2, "green", false);
  System.out.println(sq3);
  // Test Setters and Getters
  sq1.setSide(3.3);
  sq1.setColor("orange");  // superclass
  sq1.setFilled(false);    // superclass
  System.out.println(sq1);
  System.out.println("Color is: " + sq1.getColor());   // superclass
  System.out.println("Filled is: " + sq1.isFilled());  // superclass
  System.out.println("Side is: " + sq1.getSide());

  sq1.setWidth(4.4);  // overridden
  System.out.println(sq1);
  System.out.println("Width is: " + sq1.getWidth());   // superclass
  sq1.setLength(5.5);  // overridden
  System.out.println(sq1);
  System.out.println("Length is: " + sq1.getLength()); // superclass

  System.out.printf("Area is: %.2f%n", sq1.getArea());
  System.out.printf("Perimeter is: %.2f%n", sq1.getPerimeter());


  }
}
```

Output

```
Shape[color=red,filled=true]
Shape[color=green,filled=false]
Shape[color=blue,filled=true]
Color·is:·blue
Filled·is:·true
Circle[Shape[color=red,filled=true],radius=1.0]
Circle[Shape[color=red,filled=true],radius=1.1]
Circle[Shape[color=green,filled=false],radius=2.2]
Circle[Shape[color=orange,filled=true],radius=8.8]
Color·is:·orange
Filled·is:·true
Radius·is:·8.8
Area·is:·243.28
Perimeter·is:·55.29
Rectangle[Shape[color=red,filled=true],width=1.0,length=1.0]
Rectangle[Shape[color=red,filled=true],width=1.1,length=2.2]
Rectangle[Shape[color=green,filled=false],width=3.3,length=4.4]
Rectangle[Shape[color=orange,filled=true],width=5.5,length=6.6]
Color·is:·orange
Filled·is:·true
Length·is:·6.6
Width·is:·5.5
Area·is:·36.30
Perimeter·is:·24.20
Square[Rectangle[Shape[color=red,filled=true],width=1.0,length=1.0]]
Square[Rectangle[Shape[color=red,filled=true],width=1.1,length=1.1]]
Square[Rectangle[Shape[color=green,filled=false],width=2.2,length=2.2]]
Square[Rectangle[Shape[color=orange,filled=false],width=3.3,length=3.3]]
Color·is:·orange
Filled·is:·false
Side·is:·3.3
Square[Rectangle[Shape[color=orange,filled=false],width=4.4,length=4.4]]
Width·is:·4.4
Square[Rectangle[Shape[color=orange,filled=false],width=5.5,length=5.5]]
Length·is:·5.5
Area·is:·30.25
Perimeter·is:·22.00
```

Comment: All your setter methods are calling themselves.  Did you mean to call `super.setFoo()`?

Comment: `public void setSide(double side) { this.setSide(side); }` -- It calls itself; what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 2):

Your `StackOverFlow` error is coming from the class Square

```
public class Square extends Rectangle {

private double side;

public Square() {
    super();
}

public Square(double side) {
    super(side, side);
}

public Square(double side, String color, boolean filled) {
    super(side, side, color, filled);  
}

public double getSide() {
    return this.side;
}

public void setSide(double side) {
    this.side = side;
}

public void setWidth(double side) {
    super.setWidth(getWidth());
}

public void setLength(double side) {
    super.setLength(getLength());
}

public String toString() {
    return "Square[Rectangle" + "[" + "Shape" + "[" + "color=" + getColor() + "," + "filled=" + isFilled() + "]," + "width=" + getWidth() + "," + "length=" + getLength() + "]";
}
}
```

The methods `setSide`, `setWidth` and `setLength` are all calling themselves causing an infinite loop exceeding the amount of call stack memory allocated by the Java Virtual Machine.

Rather than using this, referring to the Square class use super.setSide to call the method in your parent class rectangle.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work, it states "The method setSide(double) is undefined for the type Rectangle"

Comment: Hi @Jtang11 you don't have a method called setSide in Rectangle. In your expected output it looks like your side is a property of Square. I've edited my answer. Try that now

Answer (score 0):

Your setter methods are calling themselves...which is not allowed. It appears you mean to reference the parent's setter methods using super.setFoo()

Comment: May I know what's the benefits of using super.setFoo()?

Comment: super.setFoo() gives you the ability to invoke the parent's method. For example, when you call square.setSide(), since square extends Rectangle, you can call super.setWidth() and super.setLength() in the method instead of implementing it again.